# Binding on dynamically-added elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

TPTB have decided that our app must run in a single window, popping up new windows in modal mode is not allowed.

And naturally, we have a UI design that involves popping up modal dialogs all over the place.

So I added a top-level Grid to the Window. In that Grid I defined no rows or columns, so everything draws in Row 0/Column 0.

The first element in the Grid was another Grid that contained everything that was normally displayed in the Window.  The second was a full-sized Border with a gray, semi-transparent Background. The rest were Borders with wide Margins and white Backgrounds, containing the various UserControls that needed to be displayed as popups. All but the first had Visibility="Collapsed".

And then, when I needed to show a popup, I'd set Visibility="Visible" on the gray background and on the appropriate UserControl. The result was a nice shadowbox effect that worked fine.

Until somebody decided that the popups needed to be able to display popups.  In a non-predictable order.

The limitation of the method I had implemented, using Visibility="Collapsed" elements in a Grid was that their order was fixed. UserControlB would always be displayed on top of UserControlA, even if it was UserControlB that asked to have UserControlA displayed. And that's not acceptable.

So my next attempt was to define the various UserControls in Window.Resources, and to add them to the Grid in code:

```
this.masterGrid.Children.Add(this.Resources["userControlA"] as UserControlA);
```

And that almost works. But the bindings are all messed up.

As an example, one of the controls is supposed to bind a Property to the CurrentItem of a collection in a member object of the Window's viewmodel. When I had the control defined as an invisible item in the Grid, it worked fine. But when I defined it as a Resource, the Property was null - it was never bound.

So I tried binding it in code, after I added it to the grid:

```
userControlA.SetBinding(UserControlA.myProperty, new Binding()
    { Source = this.viewModel.myCollection.CurrentItem });
```

And that compiles and runs just fine, but I'm not binding to the right object.

The first time I display the UserControl, I see the right object bound to it. But when I close it, and move the CurrentItem in the collection to a different object, and display the UserControl again, I still see the first object bound. If I close it again, and open it a third time, then I will see the right object bound to the control.

I've checked in code, and the CurrentItem that I'm binding to is right, every time, but it only seems to take every other time.

So I tried explicitly clearing the binding, first:

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(userControlA, UserControlA.myProperty);
userControlA.SetBinding(UserControlA.myProperty, new Binding()
    { Source = this.viewModel.myCollection.CurrentItem });
```

But that doesn't seem to have made any difference.

In all, it feels like I'm running down a rabbit hole, chasing deeper and deeper into complexity, to solve what should be a fairly simple problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to:

1. How to get binding to work on dynamically-added elements, or
2. How to get arbitrarily-ordered popups to display, as shadowboxes, without using dynamically-ordered elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer to 2 is `Panel.ZIndex`

Comment: Somehow I'd missed Panel.ZIndex, but I expect it would work, if I went with approach #2.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems really odd for me that you can't create new Windows, I would definitely recommend not to complicate it too much by doing unnecesary things such as storing your views in the MainWindow's resources.

It would be better if you just added new instances of these elements into an ObservableCollection:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window8"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="Window8" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
            <StackPanel Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="This is ViewModel1!!"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
            <StackPanel Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="This is ViewModel2!!"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel3}">
            <StackPanel Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="This is ViewModel3!!"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text3}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text3}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Width="100" Content="Add" Click="Add_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Button Width="100" Content="Remove" Click="Remove_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveWidgets}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWidget}">
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class Window8 : Window
    {
        private WidgetsViewModel Widgets { get; set; }

        public Window8()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = Widgets = new WidgetsViewModel();
        }

        private Random rnd = new Random();
        private int lastrandom;
        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var random = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            while (random == lastrandom)
            {
                random = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            }

            lastrandom = random;

            switch (random)
            {
                case 1:
                    Widgets.ActiveWidgets.Add(new ViewModel1() {Text = "This is a Text"});
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Widgets.ActiveWidgets.Add(new ViewModel2() { Text2 = "This is another Text" });
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Widgets.ActiveWidgets.Add(new ViewModel3() { Text3 = "This is yet another Text" });
                    break;
            }

            Widgets.SelectedWidget = Widgets.ActiveWidgets.LastOrDefault();

        }

        private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Widgets.ActiveWidgets.Remove(Widgets.SelectedWidget);
            Widgets.SelectedWidget = Widgets.ActiveWidgets.LastOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public class WidgetsViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ActiveWidgets { get; set; }

        private ViewModelBase _selectedWidget;
        public ViewModelBase SelectedWidget
        {
            get { return _selectedWidget; }
            set
            {
                _selectedWidget = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => SelectedWidget);
            }
        }

        public WidgetsViewModel()
        {
            ActiveWidgets = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel1: ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel2: ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel3: ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Text3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Just copy and paste my code in a File - New - WPF Application and see the results for yourself.

Since the Grid always places the last UI Element added to it topmost, you will see that Adding items to the observablecollection makes these "different widgets" always appear on top of each other, with the topmost being the last one added.

The bottom line is, when `WidgetA` requests to open `WidgetB`, just create a new `WidgetBViewModel` and add it to the `ActiveWidgets` collection. Then, when `WidgetB` is no longer needed, just remove it.

Then, it's just a matter of putting your UserControls inside a proper DataTemplate for each ViewModel. I strongly suggest you keep a separate ViewModel for each of your Widgets, and if you need to share data between them, just share data between the ViewModels.
Don't attempt to do things like `ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Whatever, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"` **unless** you have a good reason to.

This way you no longer have to deal with `Panel.ZIndex` stuff. Maybe you can create a couple of attached properties to deal with things like focus and whatnot, but this approach is dead simple, and by far more performant than the `Visibility` and the `Resources` approaches.